# Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null (CS0649) (asp.net core mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been searching for answers everywhere and I can't seem to solve mine. Anyone know a solution for this? I'm getting the following errors:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS0649  Field 'Repository._db' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null Shop4YourSelf.DataAccess    C:\Users\ilias\OneDrive\Bureau\Asp.net core MVC 3.1\My_Work_MVC\Shop4YourSelf\Shop4YourSelf.DataAccess\Repository\Repository.cs 16  Active

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db ;
    internal DbSet<T> dbset;
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        db = _db ;
        this.dbset = _db.Set<T>();
    }
```

when I start debuging My project I get the error in this line ( this.dbset = _db.Set();)

Comment: I'd guess that you intended the first line of the constructor to be the other way around - `_db = db;` makes sense. The way you have it doesn't.

Comment: And as an aside, the compiler doesn't make too many basic mistakes - if it's telling you the field is never assigned to, take that at face value. So the first place you should look is the place where you thought you had assigned something to it.

Comment: yeah great that's work , I'm totally shocked ,oh my god  why I didn't put any attention to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null (CS0649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925643/field-is-never-assigned-to-and-will-always-have-its-default-value-null-cs0649)